# SQL deduplication with criteria that has non-unique values

Tags: sql, mysql, duplicates, greatest-n-per-group, mysql-5.5

I have a table called cc_index and the table has among others the following columns: length, date, url, [other_colums].

The same url may appear in multiple rows.
For each url, I only want to retain a single row (but all columns).
I want to retain a row that has the longest length, unfortunately, this row may not be unique. In the cases, where multiple rows have the highest value for length for the same url, I want to retain the row that has the latest (highest) date, date values are unique for each row.

To clarify this is an example of a possible **input table**:

| url | length | date | other |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc.com | 42 | 292 | adsk |
| abc.com | 36 | 312 | sdlkf |
| abc.com | 42 | 281 | sdjl |
| def.com | 12 | 210 | tom |
| def.com | 18 | 112 | vkr |
| ghi.com | 29 | 292 | tom |
| ghi.com | 29 | 103 | tyr |
| ghi.com | 29 | 101 | vnv |

The **output I desire** is as follows:

| url | length | date | other |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc.com | 42 | 292 | adsk |
| def.com | 18 | 112 | vkr |
| ghi.com | 29 | 292 | tom |

I know that I can run a query like this for deduplication

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM ccindex t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT url, MAX(length) AS max_length FROM ccindex GROUP BY url) t2
ON t1.url=t2.url AND t1.length = t2.max_length
```

However, in the case where the criterion is not unique (length) this will return all rows with the maximum length for each URL, and hence multiple rows for the same URL, i.e. the output will be

**Undesired output**:

| url | length | date | other |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc.com | 42 | 292 | adsk |
| abc.com | 42 | 281 | sdjl |
| def.com | 18 | 112 | vkr |
| ghi.com | 29 | 292 | tom |
| ghi.com | 29 | 103 | tyr |
| ghi.com | 29 | 101 | vnv |

How can I modify this query to select only a single row for each url that has length=max_length?

Follow-ups: If I don't care about the date, and want to return a single arbitrary row that has the maximum length can performance be improved significantly?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: mysql Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.68-MariaDB for Linux

Comment: A [mcve] would be great, the clarify!

Comment: I edited the code snippet. I will add an example to clarify

Comment: Are url/date duplicates possible?

Comment: If you want to significantly improve performance of the query that carries out this task, you need to update your MySQL version to 8.X. Then jarlh's answer would suit you best.

Comment: The dirty way is using variables. If you're interested in that solution, I'll write it in the below section, yet that would kill performance.

Comment: Wow, I didn't expect this to be so hard. There were previously two answers here, why did they get deleted? Can someone post an answer for an up-to-date version of mysql? I think that is the best option.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  The datatype for `url` impacts the optimal solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `DENSE_RANK` here.

The `PARTITION BY` part builds the ranking per `url`, the `ORDER BY` clause makes sure to begin with highest `length` and if identic with the latest `date`:

```
WITH rankedData AS
(SELECT
  url, length, date, other,
  DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY url ORDER BY length DESC, date DESC) AS ranking
FROM ccindex)
SELECT
  url, length, date, other
FROM rankedData 
WHERE ranking = 1
ORDER BY url;
```

Add further columns to both sub query and main query if you want them to be shown.

To your question...

> If I don't care about the date, and want to return a single arbitrary row that has the maximum length can performance be improved significantly?

...I don't believe checking for the latest date will have much impact on your performance. But we don't know how big your table is, what indexes it has etc. So I recommend to simply try out both queries and compare the execution time.

The more important thing about performance is certainly to use an up-to-date version of your RDBMS. So this answer assumes (as your mentioned in your last comment) you already use it or you will upgrade.

Try out above queries on this [sample fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GUfC42QK) with your data.

Have a look in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_dense-rank) about `DENSE_RANK`

Answer (score 0):

Check this query.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM ccindex t1
WHERE (t1.url, t1.length, t1.date) IN (
    SELECT max_lengths.url, max_lengths.max_length, max_date
    FROM (
        SELECT url, MAX(length) AS max_length
        FROM ccindex
        GROUP BY url
    ) AS max_lengths
    JOIN (
        SELECT url, length, MAX(date) AS max_date
        FROM ccindex
        GROUP BY url, length
    ) AS max_dates
    ON max_lengths.url = max_dates.url AND max_lengths.max_length = max_dates.length
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd simply use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION...)` for this:

```
WITH t1 AS (
    SELECT  *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY url ORDER BY length DESC, date DESC) AS n_row
    FROM ccindex
    )
SELECT *
FROM t1
WHERE n_row = 1
```

In the 2nd SELECT, you might of course want to replace * with only the rows you need.